# Error while trying to push in git-gui

Tags: git, gerrit, git-gui

I'm trying to push a change to the wikimedia gerrit service ( https://gerrit.wikimedia.org), but am having some problems.

After clicking `push`, I carry on to the 'pushing' window.

It thinks for a while, and then asks for my username on 'https://gerrit.wikimedia.org', and I type it in, followed by my password.

It then fails, with the notice:

```
fatal:Authentication failed
```

This error, I assume is because of the SSH keys.

To get my key, I did this:

1. (In git-gui) went to Help>Show SSH key
2. Copied this to clipboard
3. Pasted it in Gerrit's Settings>Public SSH keys, and added the key.

**So where could I have gone wrong, and how can I try and make it right?**

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you use https you do not use ssh for authentication. I think you have to make sure you are using the correct login credentials

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks correct to me.  Which URL are you using to upload?  Are you specifying the correct port?

A good ssh test outside of any other tools is to run something like:

`ssh -p <port> <username>@<url> gerrit ls-projects`

`<port>` is typically 29418, but I'm not positive that wikimedia uses the standard Gerrit ssh port.